# GCM does dot work with GPRS but works fine with WIFI?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have searched for the solution but i did not get any solution for the above problem. Please let me know if anybody knows why this happens with gcm. I have implemented gcm as per the google doc it works fine when I ran using wifi but it fails(device will not register on server and force close error occurs on app side) when I try to run using gprs.

Please help. I am stucked with this.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoaP6hcDctM  there it was answer to one of the question that it will work with wifi only